# Is there a Javascript data structure that can use a property as an enum index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, xml, object

```
    var Index = {
        X_OFFSET: 1,
        Y_OFFSET: 2,
        Z_OFFSET: 3,
    };

    var options = [
        {name: "X Offset", min:0, max:100, value:0},
        {name: "Y Offset", min:0, max:100, value:0},
        {name: "Z Offset", min:0, max:100, value:0}
    ]
    
    var currentYOffset = options[Index.Y_OFFSET];
```

[options] is structured so it can be easily saved as an XML file. But to get the value of an option without an index, I'd need to loop through the entire array each time, which just feels inefficient. A simple enum that is identical to the 'name' property would suffice.

EnumMap sounds like it would be appropriate, but doesnt help with XML element name which needs to be a string.

Are there any other data structures appropriate for this, ideally getting rid of the predefined enum entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a mapping of each index to its option ahead of time, allowing for quick lookup later:

```js
var Index = {
    X_OFFSET: 1,
    Y_OFFSET: 2,
    Z_OFFSET: 3,
};

var options = [
    {name: "X Offset", min:0, max:100, value:0},
    {name: "Y Offset", min:0, max:100, value:0},
    {name: "Z Offset", min:0, max:100, value:0}
];

const optionsByName = Object.fromEntries(
  options.map(obj => [Index[obj.name.replaceAll(' ', '_').toUpperCase()], obj])
);


// then later:
var currentYOffset = optionsByName[Index.Y_OFFSET];
console.log(currentYOffset);
```

This way the iteration only needs to be done once, and if the `options` array is in the format needed for easy saving, that can be done while still using the `optionsByName`.

It looks much less messy if you use the same key names in Index as in the options:

```js
var Index = {
    'X Offset': 1,
    'Y Offset': 2,
    'Z Offset': 3,
};

var options = [
    {name: "X Offset", min:0, max:100, value:0},
    {name: "Y Offset", min:0, max:100, value:0},
    {name: "Z Offset", min:0, max:100, value:0}
];

const optionsByName = Object.fromEntries(
  options.map(obj => [Index[obj.name], obj])
);


// then later:
var currentYOffset = optionsByName[Index['Y Offset']];
console.log(currentYOffset);
```

Or remove the enum entirely:

```js
var options = [
    {name: "X Offset", min:0, max:100, value:0},
    {name: "Y Offset", min:0, max:100, value:0},
    {name: "Z Offset", min:0, max:100, value:0}
];

const optionsByName = Object.fromEntries(
  options.map(obj => [obj.name, obj])
);


// then later:
var currentYOffset = optionsByName['Y Offset'];
console.log(currentYOffset);
```

If you can't use modern syntax or methods, then:

```js
var options = [
    {name: "X Offset", min:0, max:100, value:0},
    {name: "Y Offset", min:0, max:100, value:0},
    {name: "Z Offset", min:0, max:100, value:0}
];

var optionsByName = {};
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  var obj = options[i];
  optionsByName[obj.name] = obj;
}

// then later:
var currentYOffset = optionsByName['Y Offset'];
console.log(currentYOffset);
```

Comment: Is now a good time to mention this needs to work with Extendscript which is ECMAScript 3?

Comment: Best to mention that when asking the question. I added a fourth snippet without any ES6+ and without any ES5, I think - but for professional code I'd highly recommend using Babel and polyfills to make production code compatible with older browsers, instead of doing it manually

Comment: Wow. Incredibly simple and obvious now I've seen it! So am I assuming that under the hood the string keys are replaced with indexes?

Comment: You mean in the last two snippets? No, the keys remain strings. Objects are mappings of key-value pairs, and keys can be either strings or numbers (or symbols). (Numbers actually get converted to strings; `arr[2]` actually references the `'2'` property on the object)

Answer (score 0):

```
#If the enum is pre-defined and name is same as per enum value then you can do like this.
```

```
<script>

      var keys = {
        X_OFFSET: 'X Offset',
        Y_OFFSET: 'Y Offset' ,
        Z_OFFSET: 'Z Offset ',
        };


      var options = [
        {name: "X Offset", min:0, max:100, value:0},
        {name: "Y Offset", min:0, max:100, value:0},
        {name: "Z Offset", min:0, max:100, value:0}
    ]
    
    const currentYOffset=options.find((opt)=>opt.name==keys.X_OFFSET);
    console.log(currentYOffset);
    
    
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant to imply a solution that would make predefining the enum redundant